# Is Loss value (e.g., MSE loss) used in the calculation for parameter update when doing gradient descent?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, backpropagation, hyperparameter-tuning

My question is really simple. I know the theory behind gradient descent and parameter updates, what I really haven't found clarity on is that is the loss value (e.g., MSE value) used, i.e., multiplied at the start when we do the backpropagation for gradient descent (e.g., multiplying MSE loss value with 1 then doing backprop, as at the start of backprop we start with the value 1, i.e., derivative of x w.r.t x is 1)?

If loss value isn't used what is the point of it except for evaluating if our network has been trained properly or not??

Comment: Yes, it is used. _loss = MSE(y_true, y_pred)_. Then we do _dL/dw_  for each weight.

Comment: If you have a look here [link](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/implementing-a-neural-net-in-cuda-from-scratch-part-3-relu-mse-and-sequential-a6b5f8ea3a7f) it says "that to update a neural net’s parameters, one does not need to calculate the MSE (or any other loss function) of the model’s output; we merely care about the gradient of the MSE with respect to the output, which can be evaluated without calculating the error." And I googled this but couldnt find an example where loss was being used in backprop. Can you show me an example? @10xAI

Comment: I don't click medium links. What it may mean is that we don't need the numeric value of the loss. Just get the function, calculate the derivative and update weights based on the values that came.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly my question. Why don't we multiply the numeric value of the loss while calculating gradients? A bigger loss would cause the parameters to get updated quickly using this technique. @10xAI